# Chrome - deactivate IndexedDB for testing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

I would like to deactivate IndexedDB in Chrome for testing.

Is there any way to do so?

Or should I override the default IndexedDB variables, so my script thinks that there is no IndexedDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to achieve this, but try the following:

```
(function(window, undefined){
    window.indexedDB = undefined;
})(window);
```

Comment: Well, I use IndexedDBShim and want to test something. But since IndexedDB is supported nativly,... Well, let's say it didn't work as expected.
I expected that I can't deactivate IndexedDB in Chrome. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too late. Thanks :)

Comment: This throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property indexedDB of #<Window> which has only a getter`